# What is the difference between "dismiss" a modal and "close" a modal in Angular UI-Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

What is the difference between "dismiss" a modal and "close" a modal?

```
close(result) - a method that can be used to close a modal, passing a result
dismiss(reason) - a method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason
```

Answer (score 101):

The answer is in the documentation, right after the two lines you quoted:

> The open method returns a modal instance, an object with the following properties:
>
> - close(result) - a method that can be used to close a modal, passing a result
> - dismiss(reason) - a method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason
> - result - a promise that is resolved when a modal is closed and rejected when a modal is dismissed

The important bit here being what happens to the promise. On close, the promise is resolved - essentially, the "success" callback fires. On dismiss, the promise is rejected, therefore running the "failure" callback instead.

Comment: The important bit here being what happens to the promise. On close, the promise is resolved - essentially, the "success" callback fires.  On dismiss, the promise is rejected, therefore running the "failure" callback instead.

Comment: I have additional question here :  From UI perspective what means to dismiss the dialog ? As I understand the dialog can be closed by user either with "OK" or with "Cancel" (also with "x" on the window). How it can be dismissed from UI ? Thanks in advance

Comment: It means what you want it to mean. The template of the dialog is up to you. You could have 4 buttons in the template, two dismissing it each with its own reason, and two closing it each with its own result. Look at the demo at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/: the OK button calls ok(), which itself closes the dialog with a selected item as a result, and the cancel button calls cancel(), which dismisses the dialog with 'cancel' as a reason.

Comment: Thx, but I have another question about that : what is the real meaning of dismiss ? Is it just like close without a promise ? And the reason, what is its main purpose? What is the difference between dismissing with 'foo' or with 'bar' ? I don't get how to use this parameter... If somebody can explain...

Comment: @M'sieurToph' The reason passed is entirely up to you. You could imagine having two buttons "No, never" and "Maybe later" that both close the modal, but with a different reason, causing a different outcome.

Comment: Running into a weird issue.  I have a form in my modal which I bond a User model to.  The form has an `ng-submit` save method set which works when I click a submit button in the form.  I have a cancel button, though, which I linked to execute `$modalInstance.close();` which it runs and subsequently runs my submit method.  I was able to resolve this by setting my model `$scope.user = null` in the cancel() method, but what is this behavior all about?

Comment: @im1dermike: you should ask your own question, and provide the code, observed and expected bahavior.

Comment: @JBNizet: you're right, but I figured it out.  A stupid mistake that bites me in the ass every now and then and that's forgetting to set a button's type to `button`. :P

Answer (score 3):

I found that the dismissing of a modal is best to use if it is from a user closing the modal (e.g. returning to the state behind the modal and invoking state.go('^')), and the closing of the modal is used when changing state via $state.go or ui-sref.

That way you can use the `result` promise to do different things, depending on the what happens.

`result.then(function() { /* state change via ui-sref */ })`

`result.catch(function() { /* user closed modal */ })`

Comment: This is important because when a modal is dismissed then the promise is not resolved meaning you will get a console error unless you catch the error. I'm not a big fan since dismiss is often used for cancel which is not an actual problem. Implementing a catch prevents the error from being thrown.

Comment: This answer assumes the user is using the third-party `ui-router` lib, which is not always the case (nor does the question include it).